# How do I link a Google Analytics account to Google optimize

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize, google-analytics-4

Google recently released Analytics version 4. When I create an Analytics account and try to link it in Google Optimize the Analytics account is not visible in the list of available Analytics account. Anyone know's why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because Google Optimize does not support Google Analytics V. 4. Nowhere do they mention that. You need to create a "Create a Universal Analytics property" account to make it work